# LINQ: Property/field should inherit data on certain conditions

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, inheritance

So I am doing a simple project management system and have run into a LINQ quandry.  This is probably common.  Project tasks are based on templates (which share a table with tasks in the database).  A project task has several fields that are inherited by default from the task template unless they have a value.  For example, a ProjectTask record with a UnitPrice of 0 will look to the ProjectTask template record to get the actual price.

How do I implement this with LINQ?  I thought about doing an ObjectDataSource, but that gets away from how I am doing all the other data (in LINQ).  I tried creating a derived class with code like the below, but it doesn't show up in LinqDataSource, even when I set up inheritance in the ORM designer.

I've done some googling but can't seem to find a good model.  Any thoughts?  Thanks as always.

```
public class ProjectTaskWithInheritance : ProjectTask
{
    public new decimal UnitPrice
    {
        get
        {
            if (IsServiceOverride)
                if (base.UnitPrice != 0)
                    return base.UnitPrice;

            return base.TaskTemplateRecord.UnitPrice;
        }
        set { base.UnitPrice = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up the levels of inheritance: your system models things that inherit from each other (i.e. a project task inherits a `UnitPrice` from a project task template); at the same time, you are trying to model it with inheritance in your .NET program. These are two different inheritances: one is in your data layer, while the other one is in your code layer.

I would suggest modeling the inheritance in the data layer with *containment* in the code layer, rather than using an inheritance. Each `ProjectTask` can have an optional instance of `ProjectTask` that serves as a task template; when a property is not found in the task itself, try looking it up in the template *object*. Make properties nullable to allow for situations when a property is not set in either the object or its template.

```
class ProjectTask {
    private ProjectTask Template {get;set;}
    private decimal? unitPriceOverride;
    public decimal UnitPrice {
         get {
             return unitPriceOverride ?? (Template != null ? Template.UnitPrice : null);
         }
         set {
             unitPriceOverride = value;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great - but how does this work as ProjectTask is a LINQ Entity and UnitPrice is already a property?  I can't change how the designer-generated property works, can I?  Thanks - this is really helpful.

Comment: @MarkWilliams You can add your own calculated property on top of the designer-generated one. Rename your designer-generated property - say, to `UnitPriceImpl`, and make it private; then use `UnitPriceImpl` to calculate the "actual" `UnitPrice`. Use the `partial` class feature to add your code to the code generated by the designer.

Comment: Thank you - so obvious it's brilliant.